# How can I evenly distribute columns in GridLayout or TableLayout or otherwise?

Tags: android

I have a GridLayout with one row and 5 columns. The elements are TextViews with a top compound image for each. I'm trying to distribute those columns evenly but it won't do it because the texts are not even in length.

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_double"
    android:columnCount="9"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="1">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/ubrugeligText"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Body2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_survey_ubrugelig_active"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/layout_margin_half"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/tdc_app_survey_survey_rating_1" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/daarligText"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Body2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_survey_daarlig_active"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/layout_margin_half"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/tdc_app_survey_survey_rating_2" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/neutralText"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Body2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_survey_neutral_active"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/layout_margin_half"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/tdc_app_survey_survey_rating_3" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/godText"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Body2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_survey_god_active"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/layout_margin_half"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/tdc_app_survey_survey_rating_4" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/perfektText"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Body2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_survey_perfekt_active"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/layout_margin_half"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/tdc_app_survey_survey_rating_5" />
</GridLayout>
```

I've tried using a TableView (which is based on LinearLayouts) but get the same result as can be seen below. How can get the columns to be evenly distributed in width which I know `layoutWeight` should take care of, but doesn't?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it with a hack Measured length of all the strings, took the longest one (with a bit of extra margin to cover for the image's drawable padding), and applied it to all the strings. Nothing else would work.

```
private fun distributeEvenlyBecauseUsingBuiltInMechanismsJustDoesntWorkHenceMiddleFinger() {
    val stringLengths = ArrayList<Float>()
    stringLengths.add(getTextLength(ubrugeligText.text.toString()))
    stringLengths.add(getTextLength(daarligText.text.toString()))
    stringLengths.add(getTextLength(neutralText.text.toString()))
    stringLengths.add(getTextLength(godText.text.toString()))
    stringLengths.add(getTextLength(perfektText.text.toString()))

    val maxLength = Collections.max(stringLengths) + resources.getDimension(R.dimen.layout_margin_quarter)

    ubrugeligText.width = Utils.pxToDp(maxLength.toInt())
    daarligText.width = Utils.pxToDp(maxLength.toInt())
    neutralText.width = Utils.pxToDp(maxLength.toInt())
    godText.width = Utils.pxToDp(maxLength.toInt())
    perfektText.width = Utils.pxToDp(maxLength.toInt())
}

private fun getTextLength(text: String): Float {
    val paint = Paint()
    val bounds = Rect()
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length, bounds)

    return paint.measureText(text)
}
```

[image]